# To find the intersection of line and a plane.

Tags: analytic-geometry

To find the intersection of line and a plane.

Line: $x=y-1=5z$ and Plane : $4x-y+3z=17$.

Let $x=y-1=5z =t$, then $x=t, y=t+1$ and $z = t/5$. Thus puttinf this into the equation of plane we have $ t =5.$

Thus the line intersects the plane at $(5, 6,1)$.

Is the solution correct?

Comment: ... so where is that intersection point exactly?

Comment: Yes. It is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is correct.

Vector $(1, 1, \frac15)$ is parallel to the line: $x=y-1=5z$ & $(4, -1,3)$ is normal to the plane: $4x-y+3z=17$.

The dot product: $(1, 1, \frac15)\cdot (4, -1,3)=\frac{18}{5}\ne 0$ shows that the line: $x=y-1=5z$ intersects the plane at an angle ($\ne 90^\circ$ i.e. not parallel to the plane)

Now, plug in $x=t, y=t+1, z=t/5$ into equation of plane: $4x-y+3z=17$

$$4(t)-(t+1)+3(\frac{t}{5})=17$$
$$\frac{18t}{5}=18$$
$$t=5$$
The line intersects the plane at a single point $(5, 6,1)$